# 1 point for upvote on answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, reputation, up-votes

I just got an upvote on an answer. In my reputation tab and in my total rep, it says I got 1 point for it.

[image]

How is that possible? Is it a bug? It might be interesting that I did downvote an answer there so I thought that answer got deleted, giving me my 1 point back. But that answer is still there.

Comment: It's because you've hit the **reputation cap** (200 points per day), and after going down to 199 points when you downvoted an answer, the last upvote you received could only get you 1 point rather than 10.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Oh okay. Never hit the cap before so I wouldn't know. Thanks

Comment: Congrats! May you have many more days of repcap in the future :-)

Comment: Usually it's because you've hit the repcap (200), then downvoted something (-1) and then got an upvote (which would normally be +10, except that that would take you over the cap, so you just get your +1 back again.